# Setting audit field dates of subdocuments in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I set the date of my audit fields to the exact same value if multiple documents or subdocuments are created or modified at the same time?  All of my documents and subdocuments have the following four audit fields:

```
{
  createdDate : { type: Date, required: true },
  updatedDate : { type: Date },
  deletedDate : { type: Date },
  auditMember : { type: String, required: true, ref: 'member' }
}
```

I have thought of using the following `pre` function on the parent document:

```
model.pre('save', function (next) {
  var now = new Date();

  // Setting top-level date to deal with concurrency checks later.
  if (this.createdDate) { this.updatedDate = now; }
  else { this.createdDate = now; }

  for (var i = 0; i < (this.widgets || []); i += 1) {
    if (this.widgets[i].isNew) { this.widgets[i].createdDate = now; }
    else if (this.widgets[i].isModified()) { this.widgets[i].updatedDate = now; }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < (this.bobbles || []); i += 1) {
    if (this.bobbles[i].isNew) { this.bobbles[i].createdDate = now; }
    else if (this.bobbles[i].isModified()) { this.bobbles[i].updatedDate = now; }
  }

  next();
});
```

This seems rather ugly and resource intensive.  Is there a better way?